# Scrape which was working earlier now failing and Data-frame shows NAN why is it happening?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, html-table

This was working earlier and this is legacy code.I have very less experience in doing the web scrape
Here is the legacy code which was working earlier and in the recent past I am getting errors. The table is in this below link.

https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=818&symbol=ITC&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17

Here are the complete code and the error line, this was working

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nsepy import get_history

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime


    Base_url =("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/"+
               "live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=2541&symbol=ITC&"+
               "symbol=UBL&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17")

    page = requests.get(Base_url)
    page.status_code
    page.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())

    #Added this code for checking the underlying value
    table_1 =soup.find_all(style="float:right; font-size:1.2em;")
    for table in table_1:
        underlysingscript = table.select('span')

    table_it = soup.find_all(class_="opttbldata")
    table_cls_1 = soup.find_all(id="octable")

    col_list = []

    # The code given below will pull the headers of the Option Chain table
    for mytable in table_cls_1:
        table_head = mytable.find('thead')

        try:
            rows = table_head.find_all('tr')
            for tr in rows: 
                cols = tr.find_all('th')
                for th in cols:
                    er = th.text
                    ee = er.encode('utf8')   
                    ee = str(ee, 'utf-8')
                    col_list.append(ee)

        except:
            print ("no thead")


    col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS','PUTS','Chart','\xc2\xa0','\xa0')]


    table_cls_2 = soup.find(id="octable")
    all_trs = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')
    req_row = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')

    new_table = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(req_row)-3) , columns=col_list_fnl)
```

Here in this line the data become NAN. why and what is the issue?
Can this code be better written to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an empty dataframe. When you create the dataframe, you specify the number of rows via `index=`, you specify the number of columns via `columns=`, but at no point are you putting any values/data into it. Thus a dataframe of rows and columns, and values with NAN in each cell.

I'd also say that you're working too hard to get that table. Pandas can do the work for you. Then just need to manipulate the dataframe to fit what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

Base_url =("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/"+
               "live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=2541&symbol=ITC&"+
               "symbol=UBL&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17")


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(Base_url, headers = headers)


tables = pd.read_html(response.text)

df = tables[1][2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = tables[1].iloc[1]
df = df.drop('Chart', axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
1         OI Chng in OI Volume     IV   ...        IV Volume Chng in OI       OI
0          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
1          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
2          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
3          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
4          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
5          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
6          -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
7       4800          -      -      -   ...     43.15     93      57600   141600
8          -          -      -      -   ...     37.31     20      26400    48000
9       2400          -      1  62.34   ...     33.31    996     770400  3427200
10      4800          -      1  35.32   ...     30.48    705     621600  1003200
11     88800      31200     47  32.52   ...     28.13   4476    1572000  2510400
12    184800     117600    116  30.78   ...     25.50   3284     873600  1545600
13   3165600    2085600   2481  29.05   ...     24.67   7621     979200  2769600
14   3184800    2265600   3308  29.73   ...     24.77   4472     424800  1497600
15   7579200    5167200  10875  32.14   ...     25.98   4858    1142400  2409600
16   5640000    3117600   9499  35.38   ...     33.36   1029      96000   302400
17  10680000    4572000  16342  38.06   ...     46.34    128      -4800   182400
18   2848800    1161600   3523  41.92   ...     47.42      4      -2400    24000
19   6751200    2724000   5638  44.97   ...         -      1          -    45600
20    405600     -26400    562  48.56   ...         -      -          -     2400
21   1077600     319200   1113  47.61   ...         -     21      -2400   249600
22     21600       4800     17  54.15   ...         -      -          -     4800
23    252000     170400    196  55.95   ...         -      2      -4800    57600
24         -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
25         -          -      1  60.47   ...         -      -          -     7200
26         -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
27      4800          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -    40800
28         -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
29         -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
30         -          -      -      -   ...         -      -          -        -
31         -          -      -      -   ...         -      7     -14400     4800
32  41896800        NaN  53720    NaN   ...       NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN

[33 rows x 21 columns]
```

**BeautifulSoup Option:**

I had to change up a little bit of the code as to make sure number of columns and what night lined up/were equal. I also don't clean it up in any way (Ie. replace `"-"`, drop null columns or rows, reset the index, etc.). But hopefully gives you something to work with:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#from nsepy import get_history

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime


Base_url =("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/"+
           "live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=2541&symbol=ITC&"+
           "symbol=UBL&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17")

page = requests.get(Base_url)
page.status_code
page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

#Added this code for checking the underlying value
table_1 =soup.find_all(style="float:right; font-size:1.2em;")
for table in table_1:
    underlysingscript = table.select('span')

table_it = soup.find_all(class_="opttbldata")
table_cls_1 = soup.find_all(id="octable")

col_list = []

# The code given below will pull the headers of the Option Chain table
for mytable in table_cls_1:
    table_head = mytable.find('thead')

    try:
        rows = table_head.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows: 
            cols = tr.find_all('th')
            for th in cols:
                er = th.text
                ee = er.encode('utf8')   
                ee = str(ee, 'utf-8')
                col_list.append(ee)

    except:
        print ("no thead")


col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS','PUTS','\xc2\xa0','\xa0')]


table_cls_2 = soup.find(id="octable")
req_row = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')

new_table = pd.DataFrame()

for row in req_row:
    td = row.find_all('td')
    data = [ ele.text for ele in td ]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    new_table = new_table.append(temp_df)

new_table.columns = col_list_fnl
```

**Output:**

```
print (new_table)
   Chart           OI  Chng in OI  ...   Chng in OI          OI Chart
0    NaN          NaN         NaN  ...          NaN         NaN   NaN
0    NaN          NaN         NaN  ...          NaN         NaN   NaN
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...        2,400       2,400      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0               4,800           -  ...      110,400     194,400      
0                   -           -  ...       40,800      62,400      
0               4,800       2,400  ...      165,600   2,822,400      
0               4,800           -  ...      576,000     957,600      
0              86,400      28,800  ...    1,276,800   2,215,200      
0             220,800     153,600  ...      664,800   1,336,800      
0           3,151,200   2,071,200  ...      708,000   2,498,400      
0           3,204,000   2,284,800  ...      314,400   1,387,200      
0           7,231,200   4,819,200  ...      770,400   2,037,600      
0           5,469,600   2,947,200  ...       81,600     288,000      
0          10,612,800   4,504,800  ...       -2,400     184,800      
0           2,632,800     945,600  ...       -4,800      21,600      
0           6,523,200   2,496,000  ...            -      45,600      
0             391,200     -40,800  ...            -       2,400      
0           1,072,800     314,400  ...       -2,400     249,600      
0              21,600       4,800  ...            -       4,800      
0             249,600     168,000  ...       -4,800      57,600      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0               2,400       2,400  ...            -       7,200      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0               4,800           -  ...            -      40,800      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...            -           -      
0                   -           -  ...      -14,400       4,800      
0  Total   40,888,800              ...          NaN         NaN   NaN

[35 rows x 23 columns]
```

Comment: This is cool,Reduces much line of coding . 1. df = df.drop('Chart', axis=1) this line of code execution shows nothing to show as dataframe 2. I want the OI,change in the OI as index in the first row. 3. In the original code if this needs to work what is the change we need to do?

Comment: 1. The original dataframe pulls those first and last columns you see on the site `'Chart'`. Those are filled with nulls (except the last row where it says `'Total'`. I choose to drop those two columns. 2. I'm not sure what you mean. You want the index of the dataframe as OI, Chng in OI? I would advise against that as there are nulls in those columns. Wouldn't make sense to make that your index. 3. YOu would need to iterate through your `all_trs` the same way you did your column heads, and then just keep appending those to a dataframe. It takes time to do, and I just don't have time right now.

Comment: Let me check it again why data frame shows NAN for me 2. i want this in first row Chart OI Chng in OI Volume IV LTP Net Chng Bid
Qty Bid
Price Ask
Price Ask
Qty Strike Price Bid
Qty Bid
Price Ask
Price Ask
Qty Net Chng LTP IV Volume Chng in OI OI Chart  and - as 0 in all places.NaN can be replaced with zero. 3. sample code please i am not much expert in this.

Comment: 1). Those two 'Chart' columns do show up as nulls because they're actually links/images, which panadas won't identify as a value. 2) If you want to keep that as your first row, use `df = tables[1][1:].reset_index(drop=True)` instead of `df = tables[1][2:].reset_index(drop=True)`. you can replace `'-'` with 0's by doing `df = df.replace(to_replace = "-", value = 0) `. 3) I;ll work on a quick solution. Won't be perfect, but just to get you something

Comment: I’ve also spent some time on this to help you out. So if this is getting your desired output, be sure to accept the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187236/discussion-between-marx-babu-and-chitown88).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the logic, it was doing the JOB correctly.
The culprit was this one.

After column list is acquired and did a print and found in the website '\xc2\xa0' this was removed recently. Since we tried eliminating this that was causing the issue. By changing the code as below everything is working fine.

```
print(col_list)
#col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS','PUTS','Chart','\xc2\xa0','\xa0')]
col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS','PUTS','Chart','\xa0')]  #Experimentiing as the above not working
print(col_list_fnl)
```